# Merge some array elements in other array and change key name

Tags: php, arrays

I have a variable array that looks like this when var_dumped:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[31]
      public 'vacancy_calendar_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'vacancy_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'date_from' => string '2016-08-25 00:00:00' (length=19)
      public 'date_to' => string '2016-08-27 00:00:00' (length=19)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[30]
      public 'vacancy_calendar_id' => string '5' (length=1)
      public 'vacancy_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'date_from' => string '2016-08-30 00:00:00' (length=19)
      public 'date_to' => string '2016-08-30 00:00:00' (length=19)
```

Since I dont know how many of these elements will be in the array and I will merge it later with other arrays, I want it to look like this:

```
array (size=2)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[31]
          public 'vacancy_calendar_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          public 'vacancy_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          public 'date_from_0' => string '2016-08-25 00:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'date_to_0' => string '2016-08-27 00:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'date_from_1' => string '2016-08-30 00:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'date_to_1' => string '2016-08-30 00:00:00' (length=19)
```

And this should go on obviously for other elements, date_from_2, date_to_2, ...

Comment: Any time you find yourself creating variables or properties with numbered names like that, you should be using an array instead.

Comment: Why are you merging those two entries? They have different `vacancy_id`. Which `vacancy_id` should be used in the combined object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it's pretty easy

```
$merged = new stdClass;
$merged->vacancy_id = $data[0]->vacancy_id;
$i = 0;
foreach( $data as $row ){
    $merged->{'date_from_'.$i} = $row->date_from;
    $merged->{'date_to_'.$i} = $row->date_to;
    $i++;
}
```